# File upload as base64 string and then show it according to mime type

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel-5.7

I have a question about php file upload as I need to upload the file using a form but I want to store it in as base64 encoded string in the database. The file can be any of the file like image, pdf, doc, audio,  video.

in which format should I upload the file?

OR

if I should to store the file in base64 string with mime type, then how should I store it and how I will show those files like if I store the video as base64 string then how will I show it in the view and play that video?

I am using laravel 5.8 to create the project.

Comment: Store the file along with the mime type. Also why do you want to use base64? It will increase storage requirements.

Comment: Can you please suggest how should I save those files in database?

Comment: Use a [blob](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html)

Comment: @apokryfos what is the best practice to save the files in database? I might have any type of data.

Comment: "Best practice" (which is subjective) is to store files in a cloud storage service like Amazon's S3, but if you must store them in a database, use a [blob](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html)

Comment: @apokryfos but if i have file more than 30 or 40 mb then is it increase the db storage. How should I get the data. And how should i show those files if it is video or other than image file? I need to create mobile apis as well.

Comment: @apokryfos I also prefer files storage in cloud storage, but I need to store in my database. Anyways thanks dear

Comment: Ignoring the best practices because "I need to" isn't usually a good way to start...